# Timeout on slow WebService Calls in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, timeout

im calling a webservice with variable response times. I want to be able to "Timeout" the request if a response takes longer than 15 seconds. Meaning, i will move forward in my code, not waiting for the response. Everything is done in C#. Could anyone help me out with some code examples on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a generated client side proxy, derived from [SoapHttpClientProtocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol.aspx), to invoke the web service (did you add a "Web Reference" to your project?) then there should be a [Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.webclientprotocol.timeout.aspx) property on the generated class.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Timeout property does not seem to affect asynchronous web method calls. Here's a technique to simulate a timeout in an asynchronous scenario: http://spinningtheweb.blogspot.com/2011/02/async-web-service-timout.html